# Full Calendar Nested Events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

The project I'm working on has "nested events" in it, so to speak. The main event is a work shift and nested within it are scheduled breaks.

Is there a simple way to get fullCalendar to understand/display that? Like here's an event to render, but there's also events inside of it you need to render.

Comment: It would help to have a concrete example. But essentially no, you have to provide a flat list of events to fullCalendar. So you'd need to get the data out of wherever you store it, flatten it to a single list and send it to the calendar. Events can overlap each other though so you can show the breaks on top of the main event.

Comment: P.s. if you're just starting out with fullCalendar I wouldn't start with version 3. The newest versions are more efficient, have more features and flexibility and have more bugs resolved.